# Как перевести предложение в котором есть фраза is least with respect?

Tags: перевод

Предложение:

> A Relation is least with respect to some conditions when it is the
>   smallest Relation that satisfies those conditions.

*Примечание: `Relation` - тип данных*

Comment: (Вообще по-идее тут это офтопик - ибо 1. не про русский 2. "как перевести") Это же из ECMAScript Shared Memory and Atomics, да? Ну там явно *the* пропущено перед *least*. Хотя и так и так сложно придумать нормальный перевод чтоб не звучал как масло масленное... Что-то типа: "Relation является наименьшим по отношению к неким условиям в том случае, если [это самое] Relation менее всего удовлетворяет этим (самым) условиям".

Comment: Тут основная проблема в том, что Relation ну очень специфический тип данных (насколько я понимаю его главное назначение задавать отношения (порядок выполнения?) между значениями типа "execution") и так вот сходу придумать подходящее слово к "the least" в отношении того что там на самом деле происходит довольно сложно. Там весь этот раздел и по-английски странновато (мягко говоря) звучит. Так что тут, как водится (почти всегда для такого рода спецификаций), не переводить надо, а (почти) с нуля выдумывать всю русскую терминологию.

Comment: @seven-phases-max ага из ECMAScript. Просто я логически не понимаю смысл этого предложения, а он там ключевой. И это не из Shared Memory and Atomics а из более ранних глав, но да концепция Relation там используется. Ну терминологию не обязательно выдумывать можно просто оставить типы как есть без перевода, тогда и масла не получится. 

P.S Да скорее всего оффтопик, просто где это спросить чтобы нормально ответили, я не знаю.

Comment: *Да скорее всего оффтопик, просто где это спросить чтобы нормально ответили* - Если переделать слегка в "как по-русски наиболее точно выразить эту фразу" то уже вроде как и не офтопик :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В математике говорят: "наиболее слабое условие".

Например:

"Из приведённых условий сходимости условие (1) является самым слабым,
ибо все другие перечисленные условия влекут за собой не просто сходимость, но сходимость равномерную."

Говорят также: "наиболее слабый критерий" и в некоторых случаях "наиболее слабое отношение".

Например, из двух отношений "а < с" и "а ≤ с" последнее является более слабым в смысле сравнения значений двух величин.

Потому указанное предложение я бы перевёл так:

"Отношение является слабейшим по отношению к какому-то заданному условию, если оно содержит в себе минимальные требования, обеспечивающие выполнение этого условия."

В принципе, можно заменить "является слабейшим" на "является минимальным", но тогда в переводе возникнет тавтология. К тому же, у математиков действительно в ходу такие термины, как "слабое условие" и "сильное условие". Например, вот здесь сказано:

"Это гораздо более слабое условие, чем любое условие Гёльдера."

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99413/discussion-on-answer-by-michael-1812-------).